# Can a web admin be able to see changes I've made to the CSS & Html?

Tags: html, css

I know that in the case that changing CSS & Html of a website through developer tools doesn't result in any permanent changes to a website but I'm wondering if a website is able to detect that there was any temporary changes to their CSS or Html at all?

Answer (score 1):

No, the changes in Developer Console only happens in client side. Server side / web admin won't detect such changes.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit a website with the **[F12 Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx)**, you're editing a **cached** copy of it. It's a local instance, and **cannot** be viewed by anyone other than you. No server-side scripts will be able to see changes you make either.

To that extent, you are free to make changes through the F12 Debugger without interference. In fact, that's one of the ways how web developers are able to debug code remotely, as debugging with F12 does **not** update the **DOM** (it would be a serious security issue if it did).

In order for others to be able to see changes you make, you need to **commit** those changes to the website through a **file upload**, then others **will** be able to see them, as they'll be stored on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

If it's through developer tools - it can't.

The website is stored on the webserver. The browser downloads it and renders it on your computer. Editing in developer tools only edits a copy on your computer in your browser, the original on the webserver remains unchanged.